# Get Return value from stored procedure call in Mule 3.5.0 ESB

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, mule

Using Mule CE 3.5.0 & SQL Server 2005.

I'm trying to call a stored procedure using the new Mule connectors db:generic-config & db:stored-procedure and then retrieve the return value from the stored procedure.

For some reason I can't get Mule to retrieve the return value from the stored procedure.

Here is sample stored procedure code,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_AddConnection (@pUserName varchar(30),   
                                       @pPassword varchar(30),   
                                       @opConnectionID bigint OUTPUT)  
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @rc int;

  SET @opConnectionID = 0;

  ....
  --If login is good then 
  --SET @rc = 0
  --SET @opConnectionID = new ConnectionID from Connection table

  --If login is bad then 
  --SET @rc = 1
  --SET @opConnectionID = 0

  ....

  SET NOCOUNT OFF;
  RETURN(@rc);
END;
```

The following Mule code works to retrieve the ConnectionID output parameter.

```
<db:generic-config  name="MSSQL" 
                    url="jdbc:sqlserver://local:1433;user=username;password=password;applicationName=Mule-ESB;databaseName=db1;" 
                    driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 
                    doc:name="Generic Database Configuration"/>

<flow name="jdbctestFlow1" doc:name="jdbctestFlow1">
    <quartz:inbound-endpoint    jobName="CronJobSchedule" 
                                doc:name="Quartz"
                                repeatInterval="0" 
                                responseTimeout="10000" 
                        cronExpression="00 29 01 ? * *"> <!-- Change as necessary --->                  
        <quartz:event-generator-job/>              
    </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
    <db:stored-procedure config-ref="MSSQL" doc:name="Database">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[{ CALL dbo.sp_Add_Connection(:pUserName, :pPassword, :opConnectionID) }]]></db:parameterized-query>
        <db:in-param name="pEmail" type="VARCHAR" value="user1"/>
        <db:in-param name="pPassword" type="VARCHAR" value="1234"/>
        <db:inout-param name="opConnectionID" type="BIGINT" value="0"/>                        
    </db:stored-procedure>
    <logger message="opConnectionID = #[message.payload['opConnectionID']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

The above Mule flow works and I can 
I can get the ConnectionID output variable with `#[message.payload['opConnectionID']]`.

Next I changed db:stored-procedure element to try and get the return value.

```
<flow name="jdbctestFlow1" doc:name="jdbctestFlow1">
    <quartz:inbound-endpoint    jobName="CronJobSchedule" 
                                doc:name="Quartz"
                                repeatInterval="0" 
                                responseTimeout="10000" 
                        cronExpression="00 29 01 ? * *"> <!-- Change as necessary --->                  
        <quartz:event-generator-job/>              
    </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
    <db:stored-procedure config-ref="MSSQL" doc:name="Database">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[{ CALL :returnValue = dbo.sp_Add_Connection(:pUserName, :pPassword, :opConnectionID) }]]></db:parameterized-query>
        <db:out-param name="returnValue" type="INTEGER"/>
        <db:in-param name="pEmail" type="VARCHAR" value="user1"/>
        <db:in-param name="pPassword" type="VARCHAR" value="1234"/>
        <db:inout-param name="opConnectionID" type="BIGINT" value="0"/>                        
    </db:stored-procedure>
    <logger message="Finish SP call" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/> <!-- doens't make it here -->
    <logger message="opConnectionID = #[message.payload['opConnectionID']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <logger message="returnValue = #[message.payload['returnValue']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Mule throws the following error,

```
********************************************************************************
Message               : Index: 5, Size: 5 (java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException). Message payload is of type: NullPayload
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Index: 5, Size: 5 (java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException)
  java.util.LinkedList:-1 (null)
2. Index: 5, Size: 5 (java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException). Message payload is of type: NullPayload (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor:32 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5
    at java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.LinkedList.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.executor.AbstractExecutor.doProcessParameters(AbstractExecutor.java:51)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

I'm thinking it may be a Mule CE vs Mule EE thing but I don't see anything in the reference docs saying this functionality is only available in Mule EE.

It may also be that I'm just calling the db:stored-procedure incorrectly.

Any clues to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you don't have the parameter returnValue defined in you stored procedure.

you should have something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_AddConnection (@pUserName varchar(30),   
                                       @pPassword varchar(30),   
                                       @opConnectionID bigint OUTPUT,
                                       @returnValue int OUTPUT)
```

and also de parametrized query:

```
<db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[{ CALL :returnValue = dbo.sp_Add_Connection(:pUserName, :pPassword, :opConnectionID, :returnValue) }]]></db:parameterized-query>
```

Comment: Stored procedures from MS Sql Server can return a status code that is not in the parameter list.    Reading through various website and Mulesoft's Github(?) it look like it's an issue that will be fixed in the future version.